# S3 use PUTinstead of POST

Tags: fine-uploader

I've got this setup on my amazon environment:
CloudFront distribution -> S3 bucket in frankfurt.
Unfortunately newer regions supports only v4 signatures and this is causing me some headaches.
I use fine-uploader to directly upload to cloudfront distribution and everything works fine if file is chunked ( in this case fine-uploader uses put to upload file).
The problem happens when file size is smaller than chunk size. In this case fine-uploader changes method to POST. As Post is not supported ( as in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4) ) by cloudfront i'm not able to upload files. There's any way to overwrite upload method for not chunked files ?

Comment: What signature version are you using?

Comment: @RayNicholus i'm e-tip in github and obviously i'm using v4 signature.

Comment: Ok. For people who don't know your situation, it's a good idea to include those details in the question, since this does not apply to v2 signatures.

Comment: Edited my original question to add that Frankfurt region only supports v4 signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made some adjustments to the pre-release of Fine Uploader 5.4. If you are sending files through a CDN *and* utilizing v4 signatures, you will need to supply the hostname of your S3 bucket to Fine Uploader S3 as well. This will ensure the headers are signed used the bucket's hostname, and not the hostname of your CDN. This was tested and verified with Fastly, and should work with any sane CDN. CloudFront is, for the most part, a mess, so no guarantees with CF.

As a result of my change, I don't believe you will hav to use an Origin Access Identity anymore, and will therefore not be restricted to PUT requests.

I've updated the documentation for the CDN section on the [S3 feature page in the develop branch](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/features/s3.html) for reference. 5.4.0 is scheduled to be released next week.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply lower your S3 maximum chunk size. See the docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#multipart-chunksize

> **multipart_chunksize**
>
> Default - 8MB
>
> Once the S3 commands have decided to use multipart operations, the file is divided into chunks. This configuration option specifies what the chunk size (also referred to as the part size) should be. This value can specified using the same semantics as multipart_threshold, that is either as the number of bytes as an integer, or using a size suffix.

Comment: Well, unfortunately s3 multipart minimum size is 5Mb ( even if i set multipart_chunksize or any other option i set ) so for file smaller than that size method used is post

Comment: `The file size with a size suffix. You can use KB, MB, GB, TB. For example: 10MB, 1GB. Note that S3 imposes constraints on valid values that can be used for multipart operations.`